# Looking for JOIN or nested query by which I can get the list of Providers data as mentioned below needs

Tags: database, postgresql, join, left-join, psql

Table: **Users**

```
|_id|name    |
|---|--------|
|115|Abhalo  |
|106|vesiy   |
```

**Note:-** Here **_id** is the Primary key of users table.

Table: **Rides**

```
|_id|total_fair|provider_id|is_admin_paid|
|---|----------|-----------|-------------|
|267|     480.0|        115|            0|
|370|      60.0|        106|            1|
|258|     200.0|        115|            1|
```

**Note:-** Here provider_id is the foreign key from users table.

**Output:-** Here I have to use the **is_admin_paid** flag for getting the total paid_amount and total unpaid_amount.

**Need Output**:-

```
|provider_id|driver_name|total_rides|paid_amount|unpaid_Amount|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
|        115|     Abhalo|          2|        200|          480|
|        106|      Vesiy|          1|         60|            0|
```

I'm beginner in PostqreSQL. And facing this situation for listing data. Now don't want to use loop for paid_amount and unpaid_amount.

Thank you in advance. I really appreciate your time for looking my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT R.provider_id, 
       U.name as driver_name,
       count(*) as total_rides,
       sum(case when R.is_admin_paid = 1 then total_fair else 0 end) as paid_amount,
       sum(case when R.is_admin_paid = 0 then total_fair else 0 end) as unpaid_amount
FROM users U JOIN Rides R 
ON R.provider_id = U._id
GROUP BY R.provider_id , U.name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Here is example for it : [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c116/6)

Comment: It's Working. Thank you. I really appreciate your time for looking my question and help to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.provider_id, u.name as driver_name,
       count(*) as total_rides,
       sum(case when r.is_admin_paid = 1 then total_fair else 0 end) as paid_amount,
       sum(case when r.is_admin_paid = 0 then total_fair else 0 end) as unpaid_amount
from users u
join rides r on r.provider_id = u._id
group by r.provider_id, u.name
```

Comment: It's Working. Thank you. I really appreciate your time for looking my question and help to solve that.